# Explain the difference between var and let keyword in javascript in the following code

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Please, can you explain why my code seems to work with var but not let, snippets are below?

**Snippet with var:**

```js
function revarr(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length / 2; i++) {
    [arr[i], arr[arr.length - 1 - i]] = [arr[arr.length - 1 - i], arr[i]];
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(revarr([1, 2, 3]))
```

**Snippet with let:**

```js
function revarr(arr) {

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length / 2; i++) {
    [arr[i], arr[arr.length - 1 - i]] = [arr[arr.length - 1 - i], arr[i]];
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(revarr([1, 2, 3]))
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between using "let" and "var" to declare a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable)

Comment: The `let` version *does* work.

Comment: Which browser are you using? IE6 ?

Comment: ^^ both would not work, because where destruction works, there works `let` as well.

Comment: The biggest difference is that in the *let* example the index counter "i" is only scoped for use in the for loop (meaning that if you do `console.log( i )` after the var example you will get 2 but if you do it after the let example you should get something like undefined)

Answer (score 1):

Basically `let` keyword declare variables that are limited scope to the statement, block or expression on which it is used. `var` keyword defines variables global or local scope.

If we are trying to `console.log(i)`, after `for` loop in first function then value will be display in console. But if we are trying to `console.log(i)` after `for` loop in second function then we will get "`ReferenceError: i is not defined`" error in console.

**Reason:**

1. In first function variable scope is local because of `var` keyword, so you can access variable `i` after `for` loop.
2. In second function variable scope is limited because of `let` keyword, so you can access variable `i` inside `for` loop only.

**Example:**

```
function revarr(arrV){
    var arr = arrV;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length/2;i++){
        [arr[i],arr[arr.length-1-i]]=[arr[arr.length-1-i],arr[i]];
    }
    console.log(i); // output
    return arr;
}

function revarr(arrVal){

    for(let i=0;i<arrVal.length/2;i++){
        [arrVal[i],arrVal[arrVal.length-1-i]]=[arrVal[arrVal.length-1-i],arrVal[i]];
        console.log(i); //output
    }
    console.log(i);  //ReferenceError: i is not defined
    return arrVal;

}
```

Comment: but in the let code we are  not doing anything with  i after the for loop.After the for loop we are just returning the reversed array. let i is only used inside the for loop where its scope is defined..I am confused?